# Convert HOUR format into Day-Hour-Minute-Second in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using this code am getting output in hours

with the below code.

Import script
`` CREATE TABLE `customerevent` ( `id` int NOT NULL, `Createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `Modifiedate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ); ``

INSERT INTO `customerevent` (`id`, `Createddate`, `Modifiedate`) VALUES ('3', '2020-01-08 12:00:00', '2020-01-10 11:30:00');

CREATE TABLE `holidays` (
`Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Holiday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`Account_of` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

My code :

```
SELECT d.Id, d.Createddate, d.Modifiedate,
            SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, start_date, end_date) -
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holidays WHERE holiday BETWEEN Createddate AND Modifiedate), 0))* 8 +
                  TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, TIME(start_time), TIME(end_time)) / 60) task_time
         FROM customerevent d
         JOIN ( SELECT Id, DATE(Createddate) start_date, DATE(Modifiedate) end_date
                   , GREATEST('10:00:00', LEAST('18:00:00', TIME(Createddate))) start_time
                   , GREATEST('10:00:00', LEAST('18:00:00', TIME(Modifiedate))) end_time
                FROM customerevent) dd ON dd.Id = d.Id GROUP BY d.Id;
```

**present output:15.500
Expected output: 15H 30M**

we have only 8 working hours per day so it is 15.500

Answer (score 0):

Try This out

CREATE TABLE
`customerevent` (
`id` int NOT NULL,
`Createddate` CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NULL,
`Modifiedate` CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Comment: I gave the above script to import

Comment: Can try same thing for insert also

Comment: i want only working days i m getting that in hours format. i want to expand in D,H,M

Comment: @ManikantaReddyMekala you want to calculate difference between two dates in terms of days , hours and months is it

Comment: yes  but the another condition is i should calculate only working hours it is 10:00 to 18:00